# More info in moderator tools for handling comment flags

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, comment-flags

#### Scenario:

When flagged comments are displayed in the queue, only the title of the question and the comments with flags are displayed

#### Problem:

Apart from the "offensive" comments, which contain obvious foul/hate language, to assess whether the flag is legitimate (and the comment should be deleted) or whether it may be dismissed, you (typically) need to see the preceding comments to understand the context in which the flagged comment was made.

Checking is often required - in my experience about half of the "soft" flags for comments are dismissable.

#### Proposal:

Show all the other comments that precede the last flagged comment, but of course without the flag action links and probably greyed.

Although there is a facility to expand the question in-line, it's not that easy or fast to get the data you need, and it isn't user friendly - it just takes too long.

#### Benefit:

This feature would allow the context of flagged comments to be understood at a glance. This is especially useful if the comment is "obsolete", which can be due to the comment being essentially a duplicate of a (narrowly) preceding comment - without seeing the duplicate, the reason for the comment being flagged "obsolete" is invisible.

It can also provide clarity to "not constructive" or "too chatty" flags when the relevance of a comment in its context determines whether it adds value, often because it answers a question from a preceding comment. For example, just seeing "@otheruser Yes, it does" in isolation may appear to be valueless, but when given the context of the preceding comment "your code doesn't cater for nulls - otheruser", it makes sense and adds value and clarification to the whole post.

Mainly, this feature will *save time* - something mods don't have enough of.

---

Bill added a great idea that I'm now including in here...

Display all comments grouped by their respective conversation.

Using the notification tags as a pseudo link, show entire conversations between two users as a single multi-comment entity, which can be deleted in its entirety if required. Even if that bulk action is not taken, it would be far easier to pick the crap comments from the keepers when the conversation is filtered out from the rest.

Comment: If the flagged comment is a reply, I'd like to at least see the entire conversation between the flagged poster and the person they were replying to. It would be nice to have the option to purge the entire conversation directly from the queue.

Comment: I'd like to see the entire set of comments, with any flagged comments clearly marked (the rest could be greyed out, for example). That would allow the moderator to glean the context needed, for any amount of context needed. If it's too many to display comfortably, just add that same "show X more comments" at the bottom, possibly at the point just past the flagged comment.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I was gonna add that to the question - show a back trace of comments using the `@names` to link them up, but thought I wouldn't ask for too much at first. I didn't think of the "delete entire conversation" - that's a great idea.

Comment: I was told earlier this year to not ask OP's to change the green tick to my superior answer.  When I see another user doing this, I usually just flag as "too chatty" but I don't think this is doing anything to reduce future occurrences.  Does there need to be another flagging option to label "attention/rep begging"?  Like: "I hope my answer works for you.", "Have a look at my answer.", "You should chose the best answer -- see my post".  Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306898/how-to-select-json-dynamic-parent-and-child-in-php/44380936#44380936

Comment: @mick happy to help, but I need more info. What was the "abuse"? What site? When? Which moderator (if you know)?

Comment: @mick After looking over your situation, I concur with everything said and done by the other moderators. I recommend you heed their communication, which by the way was not "abuse". Further, this is the wrong forum for this kind of communication. The [moderator help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) page, says *If you have questions about the reasoning behind a moderator's actions, bring them up for discussion on meta.*, which you have done (albeit unfruitfully). In a few days your suspension will be over, after which I hope you will contribute positively.